# Duplicates and lists with pivot_wider in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, spread

I'm having loads of issues with pivoting a dataset to wider.

The data frame looks like this:

```
> head(waste)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  council_name Period          RowText              ColText                         Data              
  <fct>        <fct>           <chr>                <chr>                           <chr>             
1 Adur         Apr 06 - Jun 06 Mixed glass          Tonnage collected for recycling 243.39            
2 Adur         Apr 06 - Jun 06 Mixed paper &  card  Tonnage collected for recycling 632.80999999999995
3 Adur         Apr 06 - Jun 06 Co mingled materials Tonnage collected for recycling 97.36             
4 Adur         Apr 06 - Jun 06 Green waste only     Tonnage collected for recycling 24.68             
5 Adur         Apr 06 - Jun 06 Fridges & Freezers   Tonnage collected for recycling 2.76              
6 Adur         Jul 06 - Sep 06 Mixed glass          Tonnage collected for recycling 251.51
```

```
> tail(waste)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  council_name Period          RowText              ColText                                                        Data  
  <fct>        <fct>           <chr>                <chr>                                                          <chr> 
1 York         Jan 19 - Mar 19 Co mingled materials Tonnage collected for recycling                                635.22
2 York         Jan 19 - Mar 19 Co mingled materials Tonnage collected for recycling but actually rejected/disposed 0     
3 York         Jan 19 - Mar 19 Co mingled materials No. of households receiving a collection                       89160 
4 York         Jan 19 - Mar 19 Co mingled materials Tonnage Collected for Reuse                                    0     
5 York         Jan 19 - Mar 19 Co mingled materials Tonnage Collected for reuse but actually rejected / disposed   0     
6 York         Jan 19 - Mar 19 Co mingled materials Collected Co-mingled?                                          Yes
```

I want something like this:

```
> df.desired
  council_name   period               type     data
1         Adur 1st 2006      glass.tonnage  243.390
2         Adur 1st 2006      paper.tonnage  632.809
3         Adur 1st 2006 co.mingled.tonnage   97.360
4         Adur 1st 2006 greenwaste.tonnage   24.680
5         Adur 1st 2006    fridges.tonnage    2.760
6         Adur 2nd 2006      glass.tonnage  251.510
7         Adur 2nd 2006      paper.tonnage 6555.430
```

So basically, I wish to pivot the dataframe to wide and have a combination of "RowText" and "ColText" as a column. It's not evident here but in the entire data the column "ColText has multiple values, not just "Tonnage collected for recycling".

I tried this:

```
w1 <- waste %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c("Period","council_name", "RowText", "ColText"),
              names_from = c(RowText, ColText),
              values_from = Data,
              names_sep = "_")
```

But I keep on getting the following error:

```
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates
```

And the output looks like this:

```
Period council_name `Mixed glass_To… `Mixed paper & … `Co mingled mat… `Green waste on… `Fridges & Free… `Mixed glass_No… `Mixed paper & … `Co mingled mat…
  <fct>  <fct>        <list>           <list>           <list>           <list>           <list>           <list>           <list>           <list>          
1 Apr 0… Adur         <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>        <NULL>           <NULL>           <NULL>          
2 Jul 0… Adur         <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>        <NULL>           <NULL>           <NULL>          
3 Oct 0… Adur         <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>        <NULL>           <NULL>           <NULL>          
4 Jan 0… Adur         <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>        <NULL>           <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>       
5 Apr 0… Adur         <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>        <NULL>           <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>       
6 Jul 0… Adur         <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>        <NULL>           <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>        <chr [1]>
```

When i check the duplicates they are because pivot_wider is not recognizing the different values within "Period", so all values of "Data" for a given value of "council_name" are pilled & I get list-columns.

I've ran out of options in trying different things, so all help is very much welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't really look like a `pivot_wider`, more of a `summarize`. Do you maybe need `waste %>% group_by(Council_name, Period, RowText) %>% summarize((data = sum(Data))` ?

Comment: what do you want to do with the values ?

Comment: edited it now, included a better example of what I want the tail of the data frame, which will help understanding the data

Comment: @AllanCameron just did it. Get this:
Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `..1`.
x invalid 'type' (character) of argument
ℹ Input `..1` is `(data = sum(Data))`.
ℹ The error occured in group 1: council_name = "Adur", Period = "Apr 06 - Jun 06", RowText = "Co mingled materials".


Please check the edits I did, maybe it is clear now what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Antval sorry, I have extra brackets around summarize. Can you try again with `summarize(data = sum(Data))`?

Comment: Nice! I added ColumnText to the grouping variables and it worked. I then pivoted as I wanted & now I have no duplicates. Thanks a lot!